# How to prevent window from becoming topmost?

Tags: windows, window, always-on-top

I use an app called DeskPins to pin windows and make them topmost and it works great, even in Windows 7.

I was wondering if there are any ways or app to make a window loose the topmost flag? I use an old app that is now unsupported but it always opens topmost and I wish there was a way to have it open normally, even temporarily.

After searching for some time on Google I can't find much info or don't know how to properly search, so any help would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 feature or freeware to keep a window always beneath others](http://superuser.com/questions/478902/windows-7-feature-or-freeware-to-keep-a-window-always-beneath-others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for example the **Task Manager** window is set to be *Always On Top*, this [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com) script will [disable](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm) the setting and send the window to the bottom of the stack (i.e. beneath all other windows):

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, Task Manager
WinSet, Bottom, , Task Manager
```

**Note:** In this case the actual check-mark displayed in Task Manager's *Options* menu will not disappear since the menu item hasn't actually been clicked, but the *Always On Top* setting *will* be disabled successfully.

Obviously you'll need to replace "Task Manager" with your app window's [WinTitle](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm). You can have your AHK script launch the app as well using [RunWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm), and then disable the setting using the code above.